# Decorator is running despite there being nothing in the code

Tags: python

I have a strange problem. I have a decorator that appears to be running even if it isn't called when initially running the program.

In this program nothing runs. To ensure this I did a grep to remove any lines starting with a space and got:

```
[keith@kb-linux ]$ grep -v '^\s' remedy.py
"""
Module to handle remedy calls
"""
import random
import json
from itertools import count
from pprint import pprint
import requests
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from textproc import remuser, rempass, remurl, templateid
def counter():
def logout(key):
def remedy_api_call(func, c=None):
def remedy_auth():
@remedy_api_call
def get_entries(key, table):
@remedy_api_call
def get_ticket(key, table, t):
@remedy_api_call
def wtf_is_this_table(key, table):
@remedy_api_call
def new_ticket(key, person, message, bigmessage):
@remedy_api_call
def new_incident(key, message):
@remedy_api_call
def update_change(key, changeno, message):
def update_change_undec(key, changeno, message):
@remedy_api_call
def new_change(key, message="", **kwargs):
def parse_tickets(vals):
def get_change_templates():
def get_incident_templates():
```

As you can see, some imports, then basically function definitions and my decorator.

There is one non-standard module import. I removed this and the issue still occurs (basically they're just credentials anyway.

Here's my decorator and related functions:

```
def counter():
    """
    wraps an itertools count instance
    """
    return lambda c=count(): next(c)

def logout(key):
    """
    End api session and release key
    """
    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
    r = requests.post(url="https://" +remurl + "/api/jwt/logout", 
                      headers={ "Authorization" : "AR-JWT " + key},
                      verify=False)
    return r.text 

def remedy_api_call(func, c=None):
    """
    Decorator for handling auth for remedy API calls.
    """
    try:
        key = remedy_auth()
    except:
        key = "<br>"
    if "<br>" not in str(key):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """
            wrapped function runs here.
            In any wrapped function add "key" before your args
            """
            r = func(key, *args, **kwargs)
            logout(key)
            return r
    else:
        print "problem getting token, retrying"
        if c is None:
            c = counter()
        if int(c()) < 9:
            remedy_api_call(func, c)
        else:
            print "tried too many times... Fail."
    return wrapper

def remedy_auth():
    """
    Get the key, get the secret
    """
    try:
        requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
        r = requests.post(url="https://" +remurl + "/api/jwt/login", 
                          data={"username" : remuser,
                                "password" : rempass},
                          verify=False)
        return r.text
    except:
        return "<br>"
```

And here's what I get if I run this code... Bear in mind, like I say, NOTHING is actually being called here in the code. It's a blank collection of functions, some of them decorated and yet i get:

```
>python remedy.py
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
problem getting token, retrying
tried too many times... Fail.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "remedy.py", line 75, in <module>
    @remedy_api_call
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 53, in remedy_api_call
    remedy_api_call(func, c)
  File "remedy.py", line 56, in remedy_api_call
    return wrapper
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'wrapper' referenced before assignment
```

This particular run was done with the custom module imports (the `from textproc...` line) hashed out.

Is this normal behaviour? I've never seen it before. I'd expect a file that contains nothing but functions to run totally clean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorators execute right after function definition, not when the function gets called. Consider a simpler example:

```
def foo(f):
    print("Decorator foo is executing")
    return f

@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

Result:

```
Decorator foo is executing
```

The print occurs even though `bar` is never executed. This is because decorator notation is merely syntactical sugar for assignment. The above code is equivalent to:

```
def foo(f):
    print("Decorator foo is executing")
    return f

def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```

"Ok, so how do I get the code to only execute when the function is called?" you hypothetically ask. You can accomplish this by creating a callable object inside the decorator's definition, and returning that. Example:

```
def foo(f):
    def this_gets_called_when_the_decorated_function_executes():
        print("Decorated function is executing")
        #conventionally, you call the original function in here, but it isn't strictly required
        f()
    return this_gets_called_when_the_decorated_function_executes

@foo
def bar():
    pass

print("About to call bar.")
bar()
print("bar called.")
```

Result:

```
About to call bar.
Decorated function is executing
bar called.
```

Comment: Aha!!!! Thanks, So I just have to re-wrap the decorator with a 2nd internal function and i should be good. I'll give it a try

Comment: Well, your decorator is _already_ returning a callable... Sometimes. It returns `wrapper`, but wrapper is only defined when the `if "<br>" not in str(key):` branch is executed. Any other time, `wrapper` doesn't exist. Whoever wrote that function should have ensured that wrapper would be defined in all possible conditional branches, or return some other callable in the `else`.

Comment: I've put the other code inside the wrapper function and now it's working perfectly. thanks